# snakemake named input files in run block

Tags: python, snakemake

My code looks as follows:

```
rule my_rule:
    input: 
        in_one = rules.some_rule_one.output,
        in_two = rules.some_rule_two.output,
    output: some_output
    run:
        with open(input.in_one, 'rt') as f:
            ## do_something
```

When I run it I get the following error:

```
RuleException:
TypeError in line ## of myfile.smk:
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not set
```

How am I supposed to enter the input filename?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the solution is to use `rules.some_rule_one.output[0]` and `rules.some_rule_two.output[0]`.

However, if the outputs of `some_rule` are named, they can be used as-is.

```
rule some_rule_one:
    input: 'some_input_one'
    output: 'some_output_one'
    shell: ...

rule some_rule_two:
    input: 'some_input_two'
    output:
        foo = 'some_output_two'
    shell: ...

rule my_rule:
    input: 
        in_one = rules.some_rule_one.output[0],
        in_two = rules.some_rule_two.output.foo,
    output: some_output
    run:
        with open(input.in_one, 'rt') as f:
            ## do_something
```

Perhaps just to keep things interesting, this is not an issue when `my_rule` uses `shell:` instead of `run:` i.e., `rules.some_rule_one.output` will work fine with `shell:`

Comment: That is because "under the hood" your rules.some_rule.output is something like a list. Open expects a string so it raises an error. When you put this in your shell string, snakemake makes a space delimited string from this list. If the list is only 1 long nothing happens and you just get a string.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I inferred from the behavior. Still, to a novice user this nuance is completely lost. It would be helpful if this conversion is done automatically under the hood; if `rules.some_rule_one.output` is a list with only one item, just convert it to a string.